# Forçar um resultado SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

Tenho o seguinte método:

```
        public ClassCardapio MontaCardapioEdit(string periodo, int tipo)
    {
        ClassCardapio cardapio = new ClassCardapio(_stringconexao);

        _conexao.Open();

        var sql = $"SELECT " +
                    "C.DESC_TIPO  as 'COMPOSIÇÃO'" +
                    ",B.SEGUNDA " +
                    ",B.TERCA " +
                    ",B.QUARTA " +
                    ",B.QUINTA " +
                    ",B.SEXTA " +
                    "FROM CARDAPIO A " +
                    "JOIN CARDAPIO_ITEM B ON A.ID = B.ID_CARDAPIO " +
                    "JOIN CARDAPIO_TIPO C ON B.TIPO = C.ID " +
                    "WHERE A.ID = '" + periodo + "' " +
                    "AND B.TIPO = '" + tipo + "' " +
                    "ORDER BY B.ID asc ";
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, _conexao);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {

            cardapio.segunda = dr["SEGUNDA"].ToString();
            cardapio.terca = dr["TERCA"].ToString();
            cardapio.quarta = dr["QUARTA"].ToString();
            cardapio.quinta = dr["QUINTA"].ToString();
            cardapio.sexta = dr["SEXTA"].ToString();

        }

        _conexao.Close();

        return cardapio;
    }
```

O resultado do mesmo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Através de seu resultado estou montando vários textbox, o problema é que essse select retorna 3 linhas, pois o "tipo" dessas linhas são o mesmo, existe alguma forma de forçar qual linha do select será exibida em cada textbox? Por default ele esta exibindo sempre a ultima linha das 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A instrução `While` executa a tarefa, até a condição ser `false`.

So seu caso `dr.Read()`, faz com que, a cada loop, seja alterado a linha de leitura do seu `DataTable`, sendo assim, sera executado até **não** existir mais linhas.

Como esta sendo retornado 3 linhas da consulta, o loop é executado 3 vezes, sendo assim, retornando o valor da ultima linha.

Não garanto ser a melhor alternativa, mas colocando um `break` no final do while, ira garantir que ele so execute uma vez.

OU, podemos retirar a instrução `While`, que fara o sistema ler somente a primeira linha..

```
  while (dr.Read())
    {

        cardapio.segunda = dr["SEGUNDA"].ToString();
        cardapio.terca = dr["TERCA"].ToString();
        cardapio.quarta = dr["QUARTA"].ToString();
        cardapio.quinta = dr["QUINTA"].ToString();
        cardapio.sexta = dr["SEXTA"].ToString();

        break;
    }
```

ou

```
        dr.Read();

        cardapio.segunda = dr["SEGUNDA"].ToString();
        cardapio.terca = dr["TERCA"].ToString();
        cardapio.quarta = dr["QUARTA"].ToString();
        cardapio.quinta = dr["QUINTA"].ToString();
        cardapio.sexta = dr["SEXTA"].ToString();
```

[Para saber mais sobre `While`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while)

Comment: Usando o Break resolveu meu problema, muito obrigado!

Comment: @RaphaelNobre peço que vc se atente quanto a utilização do `break` pois,  `break` sem estar dentro de uma condição `if` vai de contra-mão com a utilização `while`..